# Replace surrounding quotes for < >

Tags: replace, plugin-vim-surround

Given the string `"hello.h"`, I want to obtain `<hello.h>`.

I have tried vim-surround, but while it seems to be able to surround with matching

1. `{ }`: `cs"{`
2. `( )`: `cs"(`
3. `[ ]`: `cs"{`
4. XML tags: `cs"<mytag>`

`cs"<` does not seem to work (presumably because it would clash with the XML tags).

How could I do this easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closing angle bracket works. Do `cs">`.